# two-step ssh command with sudo user in fabfile

Tags: python, ssh, sudo, fabric

I want to implement command below:

localhost->host1->host2

1. ssh host1 [from localhost]
2. sudo -u superuser ssh host2 [from host1]
3. command [from host2]

How to use fabfile to do things like that. I find gateway can jump from localhost to host2, but how to transfer sudo user in host1.